# Removing all ads on viewcontroller after In App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

There are two parts to this process, **In App Purchase to Remove Ads** and **Removing all Ads on all view after In App Purchase**. I have already completed the In App Purchase to Remove Ads and it works when I tested it with my Sandbox Tester and it works perfectly fine. I need advice in implementing the Removing all Ads on all view after in App Purchase.

Options that I have tried are implementing a global variable by using **static** for my boolean which could be used in other view controller. These are just part of the code where I implemented those functions.

RemoveAdsViewController.swift

```
 static var adRemovalPurchased = false

 @IBAction func removeAdButton(_ sender: Any) {
    purchase(purchase: adRemoval)

}

    func purchase(purchase: RegisteredPurchase){
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion:{
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()
        if case .success(let product) = result {
            if product.needsFinishTransaction{
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
                RemoveAdsViewController.adRemovalPurchased = true
                print("Turning Banner off")
            }
            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))
        }

    })

}
```

DifferentViewController.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
if (RemoveAdsViewController.adRemovalPurchased == true) {
        bannerView.isHidden = true
        print("There is no banner")
    } else {
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        print("There is a banner!")
    }
}
```

Note that all the code works. I have purchased the removeAds with my sand box tester and it should give the the boolean value of adRemovalPurchase = true. But it just isn't recognizing the value of the boolean in DifferentViewController.swift and it is still showing the ads.

I am using SwiftyStoreKit.

Appreciate your time! Thank you.

Comment: You should not use the Global Static variable. Store the boolean in NSUSerDefaults and get the value from NSUSerDefaults to check the boolean condition.

Comment: Thank you! I didnt know anything about NSUserDefault until you mentioned it, and I did a little research and implement it and it works! Thank you again!

Comment: I have posted my comment as Answer. Please accept the answer so that others will make use of it.

Comment: Ok it work at first but now it didnt really work. I deleted my app on my iphone and did remove the ads again which did restore purchase, which should remove the ads, but it didnt remove the ads.

Comment: I mean I tried your code, it didnt really work, but when I tried mine, it works. So I am kinda confused what are the difference between your code and my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RemoveAdsViewController.swift

```
 func purchase(purchase: RegisteredPurchase){
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion:{
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()
        if case .success(let product) = result {
            if product.needsFinishTransaction{
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
            }

            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))
        }
        let adRemovalPurchased = UserDefaults.standard
        adRemovalPurchased.set(true, forKey: "adRemoved")
        adRemovalPurchased.synchronize()
        print (adRemovalPurchased.bool(forKey: "adRemoved"))
        print("Turning Banner off")

    })

}
```

DifferentViewController.swift

```
  let adRemovalPurchased = UserDefaults.standard

  if !adRemovalPurchased.bool(forKey: "adRemoved") {
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        print("There is a banner!")
    } else {
        bannerView.isHidden = true
        print("There is no banner")
    }
```

I have revisited this problem and found out that you need to declare the variable of **let adRemovalPurchased = UserDefaults.standard** in all view controller. This code works!

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func removeAdButton(_ sender: Any) {
    purchase(purchase: adRemoval)

}

    func purchase(purchase: RegisteredPurchase){
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion:{
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.networkOperationFinished()
        if case .success(let product) = result {
            if product.needsFinishTransaction{
                SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(product.transaction)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "IsAdRemoved")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
                print("Turning Banner off")
            }
            self.showAlert(alert: self.alertForPurchaseResult(result: result))
        }

    })

}
```

OtherViewControllers:

```
if let isAdRemoved = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "isAdRemoved") {
    if isAdRemoved as! Bool == true {
        bannerView.isHidden = true
        print("There is no banner")
    } else {
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
        print("There is a banner!")
    }
} else {
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    print("There is a banner!")
}
```